# how to get a web page displayed on my uiwebview in objective -c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to display a web page in UIWebView so that when i click a button the webpage should be displayed in uiWebview.How could this be possible Can anybody help in solving this or give me some hint

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the documentation for [`UIWebView`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

There are two ways of doing this.  The method you choose depends on where the data is coming from.  If you're loading the data from a string, use:

```
NSURL* base = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://..."];
[myWebView loadHTMLString: @"some html here" baseURL: base];
```

When loading HTML from a string the `UIWebView` needs to know the base URL for any relative URLs within the document, hence the `baseURL:` parameter.

If the data is accessible via a URL, use:

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://..."];
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url];
[myWebView loadRequest: request];
```